# AutoMapper Map nested ICollection

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map one call to another, but I got exception all the time /*An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code*/

Here are my Source Classes:

```
public class Snippet
{
    public Snippet()
    {
        this.Labels = new HashSet<Label>();
        this.Commennts = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Label> Labels { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Comment> Commennts { get; set; }

    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class Label
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Snippet> Snippets { get; set; }
}
```

Here are my Destination classes:

```
public class SnippetModels
{
    public class Output
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string LanguageName { get; set; }

        public string UserUsername { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<LabelModels.Output> Labels { get; set; }

        //TODO Comments Labels
    }
}

public class LabelModels
{
    public class Output
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

public class HomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SnippetModels.Output> Snippets { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LabelModels.Output> Labels { get; set; }
}
```

And finally I tied everything that pop up in my mind but no success:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Snippy.Models.Label, LabelModels.Output>();
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Snippy.Models.Label>, IEnumerable<LabelModels.Output>>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Snippy.Models.Snippet, SnippetModels.Output>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Labels, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Labels));
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Snippy.Models.Snippet>, IEnumerable<SnippetModels.Output>>();

var newestSnippetsDatabase = this.Data.Snippets
    .All()
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.CreatedOn)
    .Take(HomeVisibleItemsCount)
    .Select(s => s)
    .ToList();

var homeScreenView = new HomeViewModel
{
    Snippets = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SnippetModels.Output>>(newestSnippetsDatabase)
};
```

Comment: you should be able to get more information about the exception than just `An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred `  that extra information would be helpful

Comment: This seems to be working for me when I comment out your lines that CreateMap on the IEnumerables.  AutoMapper has built in support for generic collections.

Comment: @TylerOhlsen is correct, you do not need to create `Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Snippy.Models.Label>, IEnumerable<LabelModels.Output>>()`, only `Mapper.CreateMap<Snippy.Models.Label, LabelModels.Output>();`.